# Severe Ringing when turning off bench supply

Tags: power-supply

I have an HP E3610A and I've noticed a huge amount of ringing/hash when turning the supply on and off.  This is my test circuit.  The bench supply is set to 6V.  There are 2 clip leads (about 18" long) connected to a 0.1µF, 22pF, and 50 resistor all in parallel.  This is to simulate a load with some decoupling capacitance.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fw1xtg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When I turn the bench supply off there is a lot of ringing that gets up to almost double the set 6V, and I suspect this ringing is damaging devices attached to the power supply.

[image]

I tried @AliChen 's suggestion of checking the AC grounding.  Both the scope and supply are plugged into the same power strip, and I used a ground tip spring on the scope probe.  This is what I got:

[image]

I've tried wrapping the positive lead a couple of times through a choke and that did not help.

What is causing this ringing and what can I do to stop it?

Comment: I would try other power supplies.

Comment: @Uwe I've tried 2 other supplies that just have a single on/off switch.  I've been looking at other supplies online that have an on/off switch for turning the supply on and off, and a separate switch for turning the output on and off.  Unfortunately, all 3 supplies I have exhibit this same problem.

Comment: What kind of probe do you use? Try a passive coax cable with 1k resistor tip. This could be some parasitic coupling over the air into your scope ground lead.

Comment: @Uwe The [HP E3610](https://www.keysight.com/en/pd-838240-pn-E3610A/30w-power-supply-8v-3a-or-15v-2a) is an older, but rather respectable lab power supply. I wouldn't be inclined to blame it here.

Comment: @AliChen Agilent 10073D directly across the load resistor.  https://www.keysight.com/en/pd-1871575-pn-10073D/passive-probe-101-500-mhz-15-m?cc=US&lc=eng

Comment: The signal looks like a typical arching from a high-voltage AC toggle switch. You need to check your AC grounding between the scope and PSU, and avoid long ground leads on your probe.

Comment: I agree with @Ali, this is probably not real. Just EMI from the AC switch.

Comment: Is the DC earth grounded from long scope probe inductive leads that have a high Q resonance below 20MHz

Comment: A better RF measurement is to use 1nF series cap to 50 ohm terminated coax to scope 1:1 with <1cm gap to  load caps. Using good quality coax or FET probes or calibrated spring probe 10:1 directly across Cap.

Comment: If this fails then the power relay or switch needs debounce RC snubber across it. X rated cap 1nF and 100 Ohms 1W

Comment: 1 meter of wire (about 1uH) and 1uF will ring at 0.16MHz.

Comment: @AliChen Looks like you are correct.  I see the same spikes from multiple power supplies, even with the scope probe NOT connected to the power supply output.  Those spikes show up with the ground lead on the probe connected to the tip.